# strange problem with a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor

I have a really bizarre issue here...
I'm using [this 6-24v DC motor](https://www.banggood.com/RS-550-Motor-DC-6-24V-High-Speed-Large-Torque-Motor-p-1195170.html?rmmds=search) which I connect to a 18v power source. When I connect it as it is, it runs smooth and strong, high rpm. All good here! BUT once I attach a small fan to it, it suddenly runs very slowly, weak, and in pulses (not in constant rate). 
[This video demonstrates the problem](https://youtu.be/lbin8y6XQoI) (turn sound on to hear how weak and irregular the motor runs with the fan on it).
Can anyone explain me why this happens? How to try and solve it?
I have no idea what is happening here.
(The fan is made of 3d printed parts (PLA) and a metal sheet, and it is lightweight)

Comment: Could be defective, or the collector/brushes are new and need to get be more weraed to make a good contact. The collector is maybe loosing contact. Try to run it for a while, if probem persits, then it is deffective.

Comment: Are you measuring the actual voltage at the motor when the fan is on it to be sure your power supply isn't in current limit?  Seems like it might be a hiccup current limit in your supply.

Comment: the amount of air the fan moves also needs to be considered - that is a large part of the load the fan presents.

Comment: From the blade pitch, fan area, and RPM at 18V, you can calculate the power requirements (either from basic physics; volume of air moved per second * density = mass (per second), airflow velocity, kinetic energy imparted to that mass - or find propeller power formulae online. Now are you sure your power supply is up to that power? I think it's giving up and shutting down.

Comment: The motor is spec'd to do 22500rpm at 18V without a load. Your fan looks to be about 100mm diameter, has a large blade area and probably isn't well balanced. It is not a small load for that motor. "...made of 3d printed parts (PLA) and a metal sheet" - you are lucky it didn't get up to speed. At 20000rpm that thing would be lethal!

Comment: Looks to me that the fan blades are flexing (under loading/poor balancing) and as a result the rotating system is trying to enter into some mechanical resonance and producing the inconstant rpms. If the fan blades are thin they will flex. In addition if the blades are not balanced this will just add to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The power supply is probably not capable of providing the necessary current. The fan may seem to be lightweight, but the inertia may still present sufficient load to pull enough current to shut down the power supply. As soon as the power supply shuts down, the load drops and the power supply recovers.

Unfortunately the seller does not provide full specifications. The motor is likely to pull 10 amps or more during acceleration. With nothing on the shaft, the motor comes up to speed before the power supply reacts to the high current. The current may not even rise to the maximum during the quick, no-load acceleration.

The power required to drive a fan is proportional to the cube of the fan speed. If you measure the voltage and current at one speed and calculate power = V X I, the required power will be multiplied X 8 at 2 X speed and X 27 at 3 X speed. Since the required voltage is proportional to speed, you need V X 2 and I X 4 for 2 X speed and V X 3 and I X 9 at 3 X speed. Those numbers are a rough guide since they don't account for motor losses.

If you buy a motor that has published specifications like a Mabuchi motor, sufficient data is provided to determine the current for long term operation without overheating and the corresponding voltage, torque and speed.

Comment: Hey Charles, after reading your answer I checked and I saw that my power supply is rated 18v and only 1.1A, so what you're saying makes sense, I think. I also tried to run the motor with the fan on a 5v 2A power supply and it actually worked better in the sense that it was a regular constant movement, but too slow for my needs (I'm building a small vacuum cleaner with this). So, how can I measure how much current the motor requires for this fan at 18v? I only have a basic multimeter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See revisions to my answer.

Comment: Here's an update: